# Having it display a unique cell range depending on which cell is TRUE

Tags: google-sheets, cell

I have a range of values, which I want to show in a sheet, based on another value in that sheet. So,

if K2 = TRUE, it should how P2:X2, however if L2 = TRUE it should show Z2:AH2, if M2 = TRUE, AJ2:AR2 and lastly it should check if N2 = TRUE and display AT2:BB2.

One of my tries:

```
=IF(Sheet7!$K2=TRUE,QUERY(Sheet7!$P2:$X2),
 IF(Sheet7!$L2=TRUE,QUERY(Sheet7!$Z2:$AH2),
 IF(Sheet7!$M2=TRUE,QUERY(Sheet7!$AJ2:$AR2),
 IF(Sheet7!$N2=TRUE,QUERY(Sheet7!$AT2:$BB2), "ERROR"))))
```

Comment: Does googlesheets have a choose() function - that is perhaps one way.

Comment: Remove the QUERY. Enclose your whole formula in ARRAYFORMULA(). Itll work.

Comment: @pnuts does excel have a query() function ?

Comment: @Solar Excel has Query powered => PowerQuery